# Customize appcompat selector background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to customize the background of my action bar items with a selector.This was pretty easy with menu buttons (e.g., overflow icon), as you can style them with `actionBarItemBackground` .

Sadly this does not apply for the up/home/left indicator. I have unsuccessfully tried, in my

**styles.xml:**

```
<item name="actionButtonStyle">;

<item name="actionBarStyle">;

<item name="toolbarStyle">;
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please let me know if it works
add this to your your theme or if it doesn't take both remove the one with android  prefix

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
```

Example @drawable/selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="#ddffffff" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```